# Beginner proof of image of functions and functions of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions, proof-verification

This is the third time I got my proofs handed back from my teacher. She won't tell me what's wrong except I have to redo it. I am running out of luck and I need help towards the right direction!

The proof is as follows:

> Let f(n) = { n+2 if n even, 2n if n odd
>
> The function goes from Z(set of integers)->Z
>
> E = set of even integers
>
> O = set of odd integers
>
> Prove:
>
> a) Im(f)= E
>
> b) f(E) = E
>
> c) f(O) = {n is in Z: n = 4t+2 for t in Z}

This is my work (she handed this back to me due to incorrectness):

**a) Proof: Im(f) = E**

Let m be in Im(f).

Then m = n+2 where n is some even number 2k.

Thus m = (2k)+2 where an even number plus an even number will be an even number.

Also, m = 2n, where n is odd.

When n is odd (2k+1) for some k in Z, m = 2(2k+1) which equals m = 4k+4.

We have an even number, 4k, plus an even number 4 which will always result in an even number.

Thus, in either case when m = n+2 where n is even and m = 2n where n is odd, m is going to be even.

Because in both cases, m is even, m is in E, and Im(f) is a subset of E.

Let m be in E.

Therefore, m is even because it is an element of the set even numbers (according to the definition).

Thus, there exists an even integer when m = n+2 where n = 2k for some k in Z (an even number plus an even number equals an even number and when m = 2n where n is an odd number.

This means f(n) is in Im(f). Therefore, E is a subset of Im(f).

**b) Proof: f(E) = E**

Let m be in f(E).

Then there exists an even integer n such that m = n+2.

Since n is even; let's say n = 2k for k in Z, then m = 2k+2.

We can take out the 2 and m = 2(k+1) where k+1 is some integer q in Z.

Thus m = 2q and m is also even.

So m is in E, for all m in f(E).

Therefore, f(E) is a subset of E.

Let m be in E.

So m is even and therefore there exists an integer n such that m=n+2 or m = 2n.

However, because n must be even for it to be an even integer, we must use the m = n+2 definition of the function; and thus m = n+2 in f(E).

So m is in f(e) for all m in E.

Therefore, E is a subset of f(E).

In conclusion we have proved f(E)=E by proving they are both subsets of each other.

**c) Proof: f(O) = {n is in Z: n = 4t+2 for t in Z}**

Let m be in f(O).

Then there exists an odd integer n such that n = 2t+1.

Since n is odd, it has the form of n = 2t+1, where t is in Z.

When n = 2t+1(for some t in Z), we can apply the function f to get 2n, where n can be 2t+1, and thus 2(2t+1) is formed.

When 2(2t+1) is multiplied out we get 4t+2 and thus 4t+2 is an element of {n is in Z: n = 4t+2 for t in Z} for all m in f(O).

Thus f(O) is a subset of {n is in Z: n = 4t+2 for t in Z}

Let m be in {n is in Z: n = 4t+2 for t in Z}.

Therefore, there exists an integer t such that m = 4t+2 which equals 2(2t+1) which equals 2n where n = 2t+1 and n is odd.

So m is in f(O) for all m in {n is in Z: n = 4t+2 for t in Z}.

Therefore, {n is in Z: n = 4t+2 for t in Z} is a subset of f(O).

In conclusion, we have proved f(O) = {n is in Z: n = 4t+2 for t in Z}

Answer (score 1):

[Image](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_%28mathematics%29) :

> In mathematics, an image is the subset of a function's codomain which is the output of the function on a subset of its domain.

In your example, we have :

$f : \mathbb Z \rightarrow \mathbb Z$

thus, the *domain* of $f$ is $\mathbb Z$ and, for **a)**, we have to prove that $Im(f) = E$, where $E \subset \mathbb Z$ is the set of *even* numbers.

To prove this, we have to show that, for each $n \in \mathbb Z$, $f(n) \in E$, i.e. that $f(n)$ is *even* (this proves $Im(f) \subset E$) and that for each $k$, there exist $n$ such that $f(n) = 2k$ (this proves that $E \subset Im(f)$).

For $Im(f) \subset E$ we have two cases : $O(n)$ or $E(n)$ :

*(i)* if $O(n)$, then $f(n) = 2n$; but the double of a number is always *even*: thus, $E(n)$.

*(ii)* if $E(n)$, then $f(n) = n+2$; but if $n$ is *even*, also $n+2$ is: thus, $E(n)$.

In both cases $E(n)$; thus, we conclude that $Im(f) \subset E$.

For $E \subset Im(f)$, we have to show that for every *even* $n$ there is an $m \in \mathbb Z$ such that $f(m)=n$, i.e.that there are **no** *even* numbers which are not images of some number under $f$.

In this case, we cannot apply the same argument as above, i.e.to consider $2k$, for $k$ whatever, with the two cases : $O(k)$ or $E(k)$.

> Consider the case with $k=8$, i.e. $2k=16$; in this case we have to apply the $n+2$ case of the definition of $f$; i.e.$f(8)=8+2=10$ and we cannot conclude that $16 \in Im(f)$.

But for all *even* $n > 2$, we have that also $n-2$ is *even*; thus $f(n-2)=n$, and $n \in Im(f)$.

The remaining case is $n=2$, and it is also "covered" by $f(1)=2$.

Thus, in conclusion, for all *even* $n$, there is $m \in \mathbb Z$ such that $f(m)=n$, i.e.$E \subset Im(f)$.

**b)** is trivial: we already know that $f$ maps **all** numbers into $E$ [$f(n)$ is *even*, for all $n$], i.e.$f(\mathbb Z) \subset E$. Thus, we have only to show that $E \subset f(E)$, i.e. that for every *even* $n$ there is an *even* $k$ such that $n=f(k)$.

But for every *even* n, we have both $n=2k$, with $k$ *odd*, and $n=(n-2)+2$ [for $n=2$, we have both $2=2 \times 1$ and $2=2+0$]. The second case gives us the result, i.e. assume $k=n-2$ and we have found $k$ *even* (because if $n$ is *even*, also $n-2$ is) such that $n=f(k)$.

In conclusion, we have shown that :

> for every *even* $n$, there is a *even* $k$ such that $n=f(k)$

and this amount to :

> for all $n$, if $n \in E$, then $n \in f(E)$.

By definition of $\subset$, this is :

> > $E \subset f(E)$.

Comment: I understand Im(f) subset E, but I don't quite understand E subset Im(f), maybe clarify a bit more for me please

Comment: @ShawnS.Rana - in order to prove that $E \subset f(E)$, we have to show that : for every $n \in E$, we have that $n \in f(E)$ (by def of $\subset$). I.e.: for every *even* $n$ [this is $n \in E$] there is an *even* $k$ such that $n=f(k)$. But if $n$ is *even* then it is "mapped" by $f$ in two ways: as $n=2k$, with $k$ odd, ans as $n=(n-2)+2$, if $n-2$ is also even. Thus, we have found the *even* $k$ such that $n=f(k)$: it is sufficient to use $k=n-2$.

Comment: @ShawnS.Rana -  *Please*, see edit of the answer.